# Eclipse Maven multi project build/deploy process when using a SCM/Audit group

Tags: eclipse, maven, version-control

Ultimately we are trying to figure out a build/deploy process at my company.  As the developer, I need to provide my source code to an audit group.  They review the software for security deviations.  If the source passes the audit, then the code goes to the Software Configuration Group.  Their job is to archive and compile my app to a WAR.  The WAR file is then provided to the IT department who will put the WAR on the server.  I think the process would be easy if I had one self contained project.

But in Eclipse I have two Maven projects, where one depends on the other. One project `core` provides core functionality. I separated it because these core functionalites will be used by all my other (internal) web app projects.

```
 Logging
 filters
 common models (phonebook, employee, etc)
 common utilities (Emailing employess, String utils, etc..)
```

In the other projects, say `project1`, I add a dependency to `core` in the POM. Not sure if I need to do this but I also edited the Eclipse project properties and added a reference to the `core` project.  With some finagling (new to Maven) I was able to get `Project1` deployed to my local install of JBoss.  I opened the WAR and in WEB-INF/lib folder I could see that `core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` was automatically included.

But how do I give SCM my source for `project1` which also needs the source for `core` without manually copying `cores` source into `porject1s` source.

I could copy `core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` into `Project1` but they should also be reviewing `cores` source every time I deploy a new app because I may have added or tweaked some core functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn more about maven SNAPSHOT and release repositories. Then install [Nexus server](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) as destination for produced jars, wars, javadocs and sources (called artifacts).

After that maybe you will be interested in commercial Nexus version with staged deployment option.
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/using-staging-repositories-for-deployment-in-nexus/

Comment: I advice you to learn more about maven. For example, having SNAPSHOT version in released package is bad style. Your relases should not be SNAPSHOT, but have incremented versions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it

Comment: I agree I need to learn more about Maven.  I agree about SNAPSHOT, But what I am missing is the mechanics of coordinating with 2 other people who take control of my source code.  If I had 1 standalone module, I could zip that folder.  But in Eclipse I have two separate projects that need to get built into 1 WAR by someone else, not me.  I have been learning about Multi-Module.  I also just did the sonatype book example where the maven assemply plugin was used.

Comment: Why not let them get code via SCM (version control)? Just have 2 project under 1 folder for ease of updates, commits.

Answer (score 1):

To solve packaging problem you can use [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). You can have all sources and dependencies in one file.

Maybe there are even more suitable for your needs maven plugins.