# Error finding jpa-ddl-maven-plugin for DDL Generation from JPA Entities

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm trying to use the jpa-ddl-maven-plugin as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/jpa-ddl-maven-plugin/wiki/UsageExamples) but I'm getting a the below error using Apache Maven 3.0.3. Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

**my pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>

                   <groupId>it.linksmt.tooling</groupId>

                   <artifactId>maven-jpa-ddl-plugin</artifactId>

                   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                   <extensions>true</extensions>

                   <configuration>

                           <targetDbPlatform>OraclePlatform</targetDbPlatform>

                           <persistenceUnitName>test-entity-api</persistenceUnitName>

                           <persistenceUnitFile>META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceUnitFile>

                   </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

**settings.xml:**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>it.linksmt.tooling</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

**Error:**

```
WARNING] The POM for it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test.sample:sample-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/project/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

**mvn clean install -e output:**

```
ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test:sample:sample-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/project/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.resolveExtensionArtifacts(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled(DefaultModelBuildingListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire(ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:43)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1041)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:391)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:536)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:542)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:542)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:632)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:581)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:207)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact it.linksmt.tooling:maven-jpa-ddl-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:531)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a [SNAPSHOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it) version of the plugin, which will not be found in Maven's default repository - [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).
Looking at the plugin Google code page, it seems that it is currently in beta and has no release version.
You have a couple of options for resolving this plugin:

1. build it from the source as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/jpa-ddl-maven-plugin/wiki/HowToBuild) and install it to your local Maven repository. This will be useful only on your machine.
2. build the plugin and [deploy](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+via+the+Web+UI) it to a repository manager such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview). This will help you sharing the plugin with other team members/CI server.
3. Resolve the plugin from this [repository](https://workspace.gft.com/GFTmvnproxy/list/Assets-Repository/). Notice, I found it by searching Google, but have no idea who is managing it. You will have to define a new [repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) for this.