# How do I clear teamcity's maven dependency repository/cache

Tags: maven, teamcity

I have a teamcity server and I have maven dependencies which have changed but who's versions have not changed. From what I can tell this is causing my build to fail because teamcity is not updating these dependencies.

So I need to know how to clear out teamcity's maven dependency cache for my project. I looked through the documentation and didn't find anything significant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to manually clear the local Maven repository on the server running Teamcity, it may be easier to force an update of the Maven dependencies in the Teamcity settings.

To do this, edit the settings for the Teamcity project (in the Teamcity frontend select the project and then select the 'Settings' tab). Next click the 'Edit Configuration Settings' link (top right) and then click the 'Build Steps' link on the right hand side. In here, edit the step responsible for compiling the code. On this form, in the 'Goals' field, add the argument `-U` (that's an uppercase 'U').

Save the settings and kick off a new build. That extra argument will force Maven to go and update its dependencies.

Going forward, if the dependencies are changing but their versions are not, you may be better to have their versions set as SNAPSHOT. See [What exactly is a Maven Snapshot and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, are you sure it should? Also, I unfortunately cannot use snapshots because I don't control these particular dependencies :/ Any other ideas?

Comment: It should work. That's the way we have the build configured for our Teamcity setup. You could try logging on to your Teamcity server, change to the teamcity user (or whatever user Teamcity runs as) and then forcibly remove (or rename) the .m2 folder. That's the local maven cache. The next time Teamcity runs the build, maven will download all the dependencies again.

Comment: I had the same problem and came to the same solution. For one build it worked, for another it seems like Maven ignores the `-U` switch. Lovely ...

Answer (score 1):

Found mine at `/opt/buildagent/system/jetbrains.maven.runner/maven.repo.local`.

Answer (score 0):

I found mine in `/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/system/sbt_ivy/cache/`, But if you can SSH to your machine, just run `sudo find / -name "sbt_ivy"` and you'll see the address of ivy in your machine (if you use SBT as I do)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually go to Version Control Settings and there is a checkbox "Delete all files in the checkout directory before the build".