# Managing dependencies via maven easily

Tags: maven

On my team we have a common module (project C) used by 2 other projects:

Project A --> Project C

Project B --> Project C

We are all using  maven 3. There is also a Artifactory server available to us.

I really don't want the hassle of updating Project A and B poms everytime there is an update to project C. I just want the latest version.

At the same time, I don't want to have to keep updating the pom for project C everytime there is a change there.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't update the pom for project C, how would other projects that depend on project C understand that there has been a change? But yes, unfortunately, it is possible.

Comment: If the modules are all under development then you can use [SNAPSHOTS](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions). This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5907727/1570834.

Comment: baba - we use continuous integration. The idea is when project C is changed, project A and B will automatically build, taking in the new Project C, and run all tests.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can take a look at this:
[How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Basically, you can configure A and B to rely on latest version of C.
For C, you can configure a hook in git or some other thing, to update the version of C automatically each time there is a change in it. See:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/

Comment: I'm reluctant to use the maven release plugin as it seems complicated to setup. If setting project C to 1.0-SNAPSHOT permanently is an option and have project A and B configured to always look for a newer version, that would be better. Any issues?