# Meaning of "SNAPSHOT" version in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

While working on multiple projects I come cross a lot of cases in which the version number has a *-SNAPSHOT* suffix. For example

```
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Why is this naming used? Couldn't people just use a different version number? What exactly hides behind the meaning of the snapshot suffix?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A snapshot version is a version that is currently under development and not production-ready.

It is also a guideline that you shouldn't use this version in your application, since its API is not guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: Content of a -SNAPSHOT artifact is also considered mutable - i.e. maven will check periodically if there isn't a more recent .jar with the same version. Non -SNAPSHOT versions are considered immutable (i.e. if we have cached foo-1.2.3 already, it's never checked again)

Answer (score 4):

SNAPSHOT means latest version that hasn't been released yet, usually a version in development.