# Copy resources to buildnumber folder in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using maven for build on our purposes, I need to copy the javascript resources to a folder, can the folder name be the buildnumber , can we do this. I am planning to copy the javascript files to a folder name with build number and trying to write the build number in manifest file also to get this in JSP, could you please tell how i can implement this

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>     
            <version>2.6</version>      
            <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-prod-resources</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>                  
            <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/cp/BUILD NUMBER /js</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

can I have some way to give the build number in this logic instead of the BUILD NUMBER text

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are hinting by the build-number, Are you referring a single instance of build? or the version of project?

If it's the version of project, you can simply, define a maven property as

```
<properties>
  <project.buildNumber>4.5.64452</project.buildNumber> <!-- any name can be given here -->
</properties>
```

and use it as `{project.buildNumber}` where you need it in the pom.xml.

If you intend to automate the process of copying files to a specific directory on each build, have a look at the [`Assembly Plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

---

Not aware of any workaround or plugin that creates directory as you need. But some pointers worth exploring and hope you find it useful
- [What is maven snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5901378/1135954) See if you can re-use the timestamp somehow.
- [One tutorial explaining this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_snapshots.htm).

Comment: Hi Mtk,   the buildnumber, I meant is version number. After every build, a unique number to identify the new build.Can we set this dynamically, could you please help

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to make the JavaScript folder common(so that if any other project can benefit and use it) and make use of Externals like svn:externals for pulling the resources in your workspace during build process.