# jar file is not updated in main project maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a "sub-project" with a lot of Util Class for another main projects, i export this to a "jar" file and i use a maven command to import this with pom.xml.

See my maven command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/ronaldo/workspace/libs/jwebbuild.jar -DgroupId=br.com.jwebbuild -DartifactId=jwebbuild -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

With this command i can use this inside a pom.xml, like this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.jwebbuild</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwebbuild</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

THe problem is i changed the jwebbuild project (something inside a class), export to jar and re-install with maven but in "Maven Dependencies", in my Main project, the jwebbuil.jar don't change. 
I tried build and clean, maven clean and update project manually, close eclipse and open again but nothing work. The jwebbuild.jar don't change in my Maven Dependencies.

**Edit 1**

I think my project have SNAPSHOT "ON". The header of my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.jwebbuild</groupId>
  <artifactId>jwebbuild</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Web Build</name>
```

**SOLUTION**

The solution was another not expected. I deleted the files in /home/ronaldo/.m2/repository/br/com/jwebbuild/jwebbuild/1.0 and use "maven install" command again, now everything was updated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you changed the content of jwebbuild.jar then you should probably increment the version. If you expect to make more changes to it during this release cycle then give it a SNAPSHOT version (such as 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT).

Comment: I edited my post showing that i'm using snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [maven-snapshots](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_snapshots.htm).

[What exactly is a Maven Snapshot and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it)

Comment: did you change the version to snapshot also in the pom that is dependent on the one that u have updated?