# Maven build Automation for a web Application

Tags: java, maven, build-automation

I have three modules of a project, getting developed as two seperate jars and one WAR. WAR is referring to two other jar. Please see the details below-

1.processDAO-this is a java Project producing a jar(processDAO.jar)

2.ProcessModel-this is a java project producing a jar(processModel.jar). And in pom.xml it is referring (processDAO.jar)

3.ProcessWebApp-this is Main web app project as War producing (processWebApp.WAR). Now this is using (processModel.jar)

Now currently after each development when I need to build the WAR file I first build -(processDAO.jar)
then 2nd- processModel.jar
and in last I build ProcessWebApp.WAR

So each time I have to follow this sequential build process. Now, I want whenever I go to build my ProcessWebApp.WAR other dependency gets build automatically in same sequential manner(1->2->3).

Any advice on this will be very helpful.

Environment I am using Eclipse which have mavenplugin. I just right click on every project and do RunAs 'Maven install'.

1.processDAO.pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>processDAO</groupId>
<artifactId>processDAO</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

2.ProcessModel.pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ProcessModel</groupId>
<artifactId>ProcessModel</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>processDAO</groupId>
        <artifactId>processDAO</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

3.ProcessWebApp.pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ProcessWebApp</groupId>
<artifactId>ProcessWebApp</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProcessModel</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProcessModel</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: so when you say, **in pom.xml it is reffering (processDAO.jar)**, what do you mean? I mean , how you achieving this via POM? and also , how do you make this happen , **Now this is Using (processModel.jar)** ?

Comment: @Gimby what do u mean by parent pom??? there is thrre project and three pom.two is Jar project and one is WAR .and last one is actual web application

Comment: @Gimby we have done this to insure that first two jar file work as pluggable component that can we plugged to any Application as of now I have plugged-in them with 3rd(ProcessWebApp.WAR) .can you please elaborate your thought or any link for the same(multimodule project)?

Answer (score 0):

Listen there several issues with the way you have created your pom or what you want to achieve.

A minor comment on the existing samples is to fix the `<groupid>` element usually it is something of com.xxx.my.company and is not identical with the artifact id.

Now from what I understand it seems that you are still changing the code on the dependent modules, so that means you are releasing `SNAPSHOT` versions (otherwise you wont need to check the compatibility of your libs every time right?). See this question on using xxx-SNAPSHOT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it)

Also check the use of the -U flag mvn clean install -U . See `mvn -help`.

> -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for missing
>                                           releases and updated snapshots on
>                                           remote repositories

Comment: yes you are right groupId should be like this thanks for suggestion but this answer is not to the current context.,and yes dependent module is changing that's why i need to build it all the time.its a multi module application bro i think you have idea about that.

Comment: see here example of multi module application http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/29027/setup-a-multiple-module-project-using-maven    http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Yes i know what a multimodule project is :)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually achieved by use of a parent project POM, the only purpose of which is to build the modules that it depends on.  When creating the POM, specify the packaging type as 'POM' and then specify your WAR and JARs as module elements.  There's a pretty good example and description of this on Sonatype's site [here](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html).