# Maven dependency download not checking change

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

**Setup**
I am using Maven for one my project. This project lets say ProjectA uses ProjectB jars as a dependency. Also, Project A, B have synced versioning.

**Problem**
Lets say, ProjectA and ProjectB both have version 1.2.3. Now when we change some code in ProjectB for use in ProjectA, we don't increment its version until the scope of the ProjectB is completed. Now ProjectA having dependency of ProjectB doesn't update the Jar of ProjectB with maven since the version of ProjectB is still 1.2.3.

**Question**
Does Maven dependency download check for Hash to detect change? Is there a switch to do that? How can we force Maven to always download updated dependency only on Update of the dependency Jar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In that case you should be using snapshots.  Once maven has a version that is not a snapshot there is no need to check for updates since it should not change.

Comment: So, Maven always check for updates in case of Snapshots? Does it use hash to detect the change or i would have to update the version of the Snapshot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it

Comment: Thank you @tom. This helps a lot.