# Maven use local 6.6.6-SNAPSHOT in different workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have two workspaces, one of which have all WEB services (Eclipse) and another with the main project (IntelliJ). When I clean and install a web service API, it appear into my local maven repository. When I try to use this dependency (6.6.6-SNAPSHOT) in an other web service it works fine. But when I try to use it in my main project it doesn't work.

The maven eclipse plugin makes something more than IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: Is the maven repository shared by Eclipse and IntelliJ ?

Comment: If they both use the same Maven config (thus sharing the repo) and they both declare the same dependency, it should work.

Comment: I would read this first (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it), maven SNAPSHOT are peculiar. I guess that both m2e and the intellj maven plugin do some guesswork to resolve snapshot dependencies.

Comment: Yes it is the same settings.xml and folder

Comment: in Eclipse, did you open the project as a Maven project and selected the pom.xml file? Or did you use something like `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in order to "convert" the Maven project into a Eclipse project before you could open it?

Comment: I have found the problem... And it's quite strange too. My project has a parent maven project. i clean install the child, for me the parent will be automatically builded with it but it seems to doesn't work. When i try to clean install the parent i can import it into the intelliJ project.  i think eclipse plugin import 6.6.6-SNASPHOT as project dependencies and not maven dependencies, that what it work fine in same eclipse workspace... Thanks for help.