# Maven Multiple Dependency handling

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml

I've microservices deployed which uses different maven dependencies. 
I'm describing my issue in below example
Example.
I've 5 projects -- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5
p2 has p1 dependency
p3 has p2 dependency
p4 has p3 dependency
p5 has p4 dependency

Now in pom.xml

for every change in project, we end up updating the version for all projects. Is there a way to keep version as dynamic or keep it in anywhere outside all these projects ?

Comment: did you use SNAPSHOT ? cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5901378/1827276

Comment: Are those project p1,..p5 separate projects or in other words microservices ?

Comment: yes they are microservices.. seperate projects @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

If all your projects are sub-modules in a master maven project, you can use the Maven Release plugin to auto update all the versions of the projects [see docs here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html). If the projects are in separate projects entirely and in separate source control repositories then you would have to create your own custom tooling.