# Gluon Charm Down PlatformFactory alternative?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

first post. I am working to convert a standard JavaFX application to a Gluon project so I can re-use my code base across all the major platforms. I am still learning the Gluon framework/work-flow and thought it would be a good idea to look at an example project of similar scale and see how it was implemented in Gluon. The project I am trying to reference is this:

https://github.com/jperedadnr/Game2048FX

My problem has been the NetBeans cannot seem to find the Charm Down PlatformFactory import. In doing some digging it seems like it is no longer supported?? If that is the case is there anyway I can easily modify the code to be able to run the project and play around with it as a way to learn the Gluon ecosystem? If not are there any similar projects I can use as a reference instead? My application is a simple variation on the classic checkers game, so it is nothing too complicated. I was looking for something with a similar complexity.

Answer (score 1):

While the project is a nice use case for you to try, I have to say the code at Github is pretty outdated [Disclaimer: I'm the author].

But you can still make it work easily, of course.

The Charm Down dependency:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "0.0.3-SNAPSHOT"
```

is not available anymore. This is what relying on snapshots should be avoided...

So you can try to find the next available snapshot or release version, trying to use the closest version possible to avoid breaking changes with the existing repo.

So far, you can try:

```
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "0.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
```

which is still available (see for instance [Charm-down-common](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-common/0.0.4-SNAPSHOT/)).

Or you can choose a release:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "0.0.3"
```

Note that both versions are the same (see dates, both from September 2015).

But even if you have it working, the Gluon project and the platform related code are quite outdated.

I'd suggest you take a look at the current [Gluon samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples), and to the Charm Down [library](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down).

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I will definitely give the Gluon samples a look. I just finished reading the documentation and have to admit my eyes were glazing over at some points (who enjoys reading documentation?). As a result I am probably missing out on some vital information. Could you explain how a snapshot compares to what is considered good practice these days? What is the better solution to replace a snapshot? Or point me to the relevant section of the documentation? I would like to know what is the best practice for my own project.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it) about snapshot vs release. A good way to getting started with Gluon should be this [guide](http://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/)