# How do we Build a Snapshot in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, snapshot

How do we Build a Snapshot in Maven project? I can see the Milestone build in jenkins, but how can we build a Snapshot.

Comment: A snapshot is just a version. Make it `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` and that makes it a snapshot of `1.2.3`

Answer (score 4):

You can just create a new version and add the suffix "-SNAPSHOT".

**Here is a good explanation of using "SNAPSHOTS"** ([What exactly is a Maven Snapshot and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it))

Comment: Did that answer your question? @DVishal?