# Browserstack automate-maven-plugin not working

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, browserstack

I'm trying to run my appium test on the BrowserStack device cloud with the use of Jenkins.

After adding the dependencies to my pom.xml mentioned in the following section
https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/appium/jenkins#reporting

I received the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:test-compile (default) on project 1.0: Execution default of goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:test-compile failed: Plugin com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:${aspectj.maven.version}, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:${aspectj.tools.version}: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:${aspectj.maven.version} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>1.0</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <jdk.source.version>1.8</jdk.source.version>
    <jdk.target.version>1.8</jdk.target.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- JUnit 5 requires Surefire version 2.22.0 or higher -->
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
                <complianceLevel>${jdk.source.version}</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.browserstack/automate-testassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>automate-testassist</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
            <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
            <complianceLevel>${jdk.source.version}</complianceLevel>
```

you need to mention the jdk source and the targer versions here.

Answer (score 0):

That's because BrowserStack repository no longer have a snapshot feature so you need to include the plugin as follows. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901460/6846745) for more on snapshot

```
<groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
<artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Without the SNAPSHOT