# How to add the themoviedbapi as a jar file to my java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am creating a Java project that needs to use the TMDB API. I am wondering how to add this https://github.com/holgerbrandl/themoviedbapi TMDB wrapper as a jar file so I can add it as a dependency in my java project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building with maven, then you would add it to your project's `pom.xml` as a dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.movito</groupId>
        <artifactId>themoviedbapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

For the future, plugging a dependency name into https://mvnrepository.com will get you the form of declaration that you need - see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.movito/themoviedbapi/1.9

Comment: When I add it to my pom.xml I get errors. The groupId, artifactId and version are highlighted in red.  It says Dependency 'info.movito:themoviedbapi:1.11' not found

Comment: That's probably because (1) the version maven will find by default is 1.9 (latest in Maven Central) and (2) you haven't got snapshots enabled in your pom. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it for more on snapshots.

Comment: ... or just remove the `<version>...</version>` from your pom for that dependency, and maven will get a stable version (probably better unless you *really* need the snapshot

Comment: I removed the `<version>...</version>` from the pom.xml file and its still giving me the same errors. This is my first time using maven, I'm new to this all this.

Comment: If you can save all the output from mvn to a file and then publish it on a pastebin or github gist and provide the link, more help should be possible