# Why does Maven download hundreds of versions of maven-metadata.xml for dependency when I explicitly stated a non-snapshot version in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, nexus, scala-cats

At my company we're upgrading to a new version of Scala but when I run `mvn clean install`, near the end of the build, it spends 22 minutes (!) trying to download metadata about these 3rd party dependencies from our company's Nexus (all the Cats libraries: cats-core, cats-macros, etc.).  This dep, nor any of our 3rd party deps are "SNAPSHOT" version. Using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` I can see some transitive dependencies have a version range `[2,3)` but in our pom.xml file we **explicitly set the version as 2.0.0** and do not have the word "SNAPSHOT", as shown:

```
<dependency><groupId>org.typelevel</groupId><artifactId>cats-core_2.13</artifactId><version>2.0.0</version></dependency>
```

And yet during the build it tries to download hundreds of these versions between 2 and 3.

Why on earth is it doing it? What even are these SNAPSHOT versions? They don't seem to exist in Maven Central as far as I know. **Nothing in our repo or any of the parent/child pom.xml files uses the word SNAPSHOT**

[screenshot of what I see in Nexus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp4Up.png)

[screenshot of mvn build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTlvw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is a Maven Snapshot and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am not writing the word "SNAPSHOT" anywhere in my dependency list. We might write SNAPSHOT for an internal dependency at our company, but never for a 3rd party dependecny. I explicitly write the version of the cats dependency as 2.0.0 in every pom.xml file but it still tries to download all these versions' metadata.