# Artifactory generates different filename

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a little problem that´s occurs in my computer, when I make deploy to artifactory, the name of the library changes as follows:

```
servico-disponibilizacao-2.0.0.0-20120117.194415-1.ear
```

In my project on Eclipse, I can see normally how this is:

```
servico-disponibilizacao-2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear
```

I really don´t know how to fix this, anyone have some ideia?

Thank´s so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When publishing to a snapshot repository Maven will substitute the "SNAPSHOT" part of the revision with a timestamp, to create a unique version for that build.

See the Maven documentation on the [distributionManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) section of your POM.

Additionally checkout this answer:

[Maven Snapshot Repository vs Release Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275555/maven-snapshot-repository-v-s-release-repository)

## Update

The [Nexus book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/ch02s02.html#d4e415) has a section describing the differences in artifact handling between snapshot and release repositories. I should think this information also applies to Artifactory, considering Nexus is the reference Maven repository manager.

Comment: This is also true for Artifactory; on top of that, this behavior can be controlled: http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories