# Can't upload snapshot jar to release repository in Nexus manager

Tags: java, maven, nexus

My project depends on a project which only has SNAPSHOT artifacts. I was trying to upload the jar file into a third-party repository in my Nexus server. However, it reminds me that "You cannot upload a snapshot version into a release repository".

How do I use this third party library?

Comment: What do you mean by "third party repository" on your server?

Comment: "3rd party" repository in Nexus to host artifacts which are not in central repository.

Comment: I see, it's a pre-configured release repository. You can manually add more repositories as needed. Add one that allows snapshots?

Comment: It doesn't allow snapshots, as the warning message shows.

Comment: You can add another repository that allows snapshots instead.

Comment: What do you mean? It seems like it's against the Nexus policy to upload a snapshot to the 3rd party repository.

Answer (score 1):

3rd party nexus repository is a release repository. Nexus by default does not allow to publish any snapshot file to any Release Repository (be it out of the box nexus repository or created by user).
This is logical also because snapshot jar etc is not a releasable artifact. It is just a timestamp version of your current build during development phase.

You can do two things.

1. Upload the snapshot jar to the out of the box nexus snapshot repo (http://localhost:8081/nexus../snapshots)
2. Run a script to remove the snapshot from your jar, store it in tag and then deploy to any of the release repo (be it 3rd party repo or created by you).

Reference: [Maven Snapshot Repository vs Release Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275555/maven-snapshot-repository-vs-release-repository)