# Nexus Repository:

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I am planning to use Nexus repository to store deployment records. I have added those records on Nexus using mvn deploy file plugin. Every file is added as a new version. 
These records will later be accessed by a Nexus job. The requirement is to search those records based on the last modified date.
Is there a way to get this? Is there any other better way to achieve this.

I have recently started using Nexus and I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus is less based on date, and more based on GAV (Group, Artifact, Version)

If you deploy your files using to [Nexus RELELASE (as opposed to snapshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151427/6309), you would get use the version (X.Y.Z) to get back an artifact.
The date as a timestamp only appears on SNAPSHOT artifacts, but those can be cleaned from the referential easily and are not supposed to accumulate.

In any case, Once you have [search results](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/using.html#_search_results) in Nexus, you can sort by "Age"

[image: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/figs/web/search-results.png]

> The Age column displays the age of the component. The age of a component is typically calculated from the initial release to a repository — typically a public repository such as the Central Repository

But you typically don't search "by date" in Nexus, only by Version.