# Unable to resolve snapshot dependency from Nexus Repository Manager sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus

The sbt can't download dependency from nexus repository manager.

Here is the resolver for repo in build.sbt file:
`resolvers += "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" at "nexus repo url"`

Resolver is working fine in case of release version eg 1.0.0 but not for snapshot version like 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Below is the dependency that added in build.sbt
`"artifacts" % "name" % "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" changing()`

Comment: Hi and welcome, could you add more information? Perhaps the whole file for sbt. Snapshot repositories are normally different from release repositories. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275555/maven-snapshot-repository-vs-release-repository

Comment: The build system generating the url eg: https://[repo-dns-name]/repository/maven-group/[package-name]/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/controller-agent-protocol-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom to fetch the dependency but this should be with timestamp something like https://[repo-dns-name]/repository/maven-group/[package-name]/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/controller-agent-protocol-1.0.0-20210910.152200-3.pom. That is why sbt throwing 404 url not found.